# Fetching the same value without updating or fetching the new value while in a loop

Tags: python, mysql, fetch

I added a balance in the app and it should be fetched but it only fetch the old value and stays constant on it, it doesn't fetch the last added value added which is added using the app while this code is running on raspberry pi in a loop

```
import mysql.connector

fetdb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="hostname",
    user="user",
    password="password",
    database="databasename",
)
while True:

    fetcursor = fetdb.cursor()

    fetsql = "select gasBalance from users WHERE meterID = 10007"
    fetcursor.execute(fetsql)
    fetresult = fetcursor.fetchone()
    i = "".join(str(x) for x in fetresult)
    fetbalance = int(i)
    print(fetbalance)
```

Comment: And you're sure the users table is actually updated by some other process? You've verified this with e.g. the `mysql` shell or PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: Yes i use mysql workbench to view the table and the balance added from the app does exist on the mysql worbench users table but it just doesn't update when running this code on python in a loop it just keep showing the previous value , i'd have to restart this code again to show the new value

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a transaction issue, where your database connection has a view of the old state of the database even when the table changes.

The easiest fix could be to refactor things to make a new connection for each request (like a webapp would):

```
import mysql.connector
import time


def get_balance(meter_id):
    with mysql.connector.connect(
        host="hostname",
        user="user",
        password="password",
        database="databasename",
    ) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(
            "select gasBalance from users WHERE meterID = %s", [meter_id]
        )
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        return row[0]

while True:
    fetbalance = get_balance(10007)
    print(fetbalance)
    time.sleep(1)
```